# What is some computer science technology that can help the development of biology?

Tags: computational-model

What is some computer science technology that can help the development of biology(eg. artificial intelligence, resolution technology) and  briefly talks about their potentials?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. Computers are used for all sorts of things in modern biology that don't have anything to do with genetic engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is very broad and it is impossible to correctly answer to it. I think you may not realize how much computation is everywhere.

Here is a bunch of things for which I personally use modern computation power

- Population genetics simulations
- Simulations of developments ([Gillespie algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm) and variants)
- Statistical analyses, incl. some analyses that are a bit demanding such as permutations test, bootstrap or maximum likelihood
- Numerical approximations to mathematical equations that can't be solved analytically.

Many people make good use of computation in biology for treating DNA sequence data (annotating sequences, aligning sequences, comparing sequences, building phylogenetic trees). Typically this kind of task can be extremely demanding. I know a lab who uses [Blue Gene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Gene) in order to perform statistical analysis on sequence data. Some people simulate brain activities. Some people simulate the physics of molecules, some people simulate blood flow through the body while others simulate how a new substance injected in the body spread. and it goes on and on... This list is probably biased toward my field of expertise.